# one div in another with overflow

Tags: css, overflow

How can you have one div inside another?

The inner div has to fit inside the outer with `overflow:auto;`. The outer div has to make a small frame around the inner div with `padding:1px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/CbZxC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the height and width properties on the inner div. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CbZxC/1/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could also just add `overflow:auto;` to the outer div and then the inner will stay inside. http://jsfiddle.net/zKAnv/

Answer (score 0):

You have to `float` the inner div:

```
div.inner {
    background:#ff0000;
    padding: 1px;
    float: left;
}
```

and put `overflow: auto;` into the outer div:

```
div.outer {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    background:#ffffff;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Sure you don't want the padding in the inner div?